# Will an FOR INSERT trigger fire after an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger has performed an insert?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

The title pretty much says it all... I have a table with an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger which checks certain things and does the actual insert if things are OK. It also has an FOR INSERT, UPDATE trigger which updates values in other tables based on the values in the newly inserted row.

I suspect that the FOR INSERT, UPDATE trigger is not firing. Why would this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which updates values in other tables
>   based on the values in the newly
>   inserted row.

The "inserted" table in the FOR INSERT trigger will contain the values inserted by your INSTEAD OF trigger, **NOT** your insert statement. For example, consider the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    id int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    value varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    forTriggerValue char(1)  NULL
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER forTrigger
ON Test
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE value = 'MyNewValue')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Test SET 
            forTriggerValue = 'A'
        FROM    inserted
        WHERE   Test.id IN (SELECT id FROM inserted)
    END
    ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE value = 'InsteadOfValue')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Test SET 
            forTriggerValue = 'B'
        FROM    inserted
        WHERE   Test.id IN (SELECT id FROM inserted)
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Test SET 
            forTriggerValue = 'C'
        FROM    inserted
        WHERE   Test.id IN (SELECT id FROM inserted)
    END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER insteadOfTrigger
ON Test
INSTEAD OF  UPDATE 
AS 
    UPDATE Test SET 
        value = 'InsteadOfValue'
    FROM    inserted
    WHERE   Test.id IN (SELECT id FROM inserted)
GO

INSERT INTO Test (value) VALUES ('MyValue')
GO
UPDATE Test SET value = 'MyNewValue' WHERE value = 'MyValue'
GO

SELECT * FROM Test
GO
```

Your "forTriggerValue" will be 'B', not 'A'.

Comment: You are correct. After some gnashing of teeth, it turns out my trigger was firing but application code was updating the values to the previous values after the trigger fired, which made it look like my trigger was not being fired in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Allow Triggers to Fire Others" setting on the server. In SSMS, right click on the Server and choose Properties. Then look at the Advanced tab.

[image]

Comment: The [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178101.aspx) states, that this option affects the ability of AFTER triggers to cascade. At the same time it says that INSTEAD OF triggers' nesting is not affected by this option (i.e. they can always be nested). Nothing is said there about whether an INSTEAD OF trigger can cause an AFTER trigger to fire depending on this option, nor could I find such information in related articles. Do you know for sure whether this option can control that?

Comment: This setting is set as false, but the for insert, update triggers are still fired after the instead of trigger is fired.